# UFO game: how to make a cow pop up randomly at the x-axis?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# but I know some basics and I wanted to make a game.

You have an UFO that hovers above the bottom of the window and you need to zap cows.

How can I make the pictureBox1 (Cow) pop up randomly at the x-axis it can only pop up every 5 units (pixels?) because my UFO moves with 5 units per time.

The cows need to stay for like 5 secs or so.

Answer (score 2):

Make the pictureBox1 invisible.
Use a timer to control the moment the cow appears (make pictureBox1 visible).
Use another time to control the moment the cow disappears (make pictureBox1 invisible again).
Use Random class to generate the x coordinate.
Funny questions this day on SO :-)

The code below will answer your question in the comment:

```
using System;

namespace RandomNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            const int screenLeftX = 0;
            const int screenRightX = 1024;
            const int cowMovementStep = 5;

            var rnd = new Random();

            var cowLocation = rnd.Next( screenLeftX, screenRightX );

            // Will generate 100 different locations.
            // In your game you will generate a new location when the timer_tick event is raised.

            for( var iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++ )
            {
                cowLocation = cowLocation + rnd.Next( -cowMovementStep, cowMovementStep );
                Console.WriteLine( "New location:{0}", cowLocation );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! but how can you let the random thingy generate x locations that are 5 units away from each other ?

Comment: @Jan Vos: you can do it like this: `rnd.Next( -cowMovementStep / size_of_unit, cowMovementStep / size_of_unit ) * size_of_unit;` — it will quantize, since `Next()` returns an `int`. `size_of_unit` is a constant, equal to 5 in your case.